Having Trouble Upgrading Powershell to 7
People recommend the following command to upgrade Powershell from 5 to 7:
winget install --id Microsoft.Powershell --source winget
It did not work on my home computer or my work computer (both running Win 11).
Current Powershell Versions and info is:

Name                           Value

PSVersion                      5.1.22621.2506
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.22621.2506
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Going by my PATH variable, the current install is located here: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
The feedback from the CLI when I run the winget command is:

Found an existing package already installed. Trying to upgrade the
installed package... A newer version was found, but the install.
technology is different from the current version installed. Please
uninstall the package and install the newer version.

In any case, how do I upgrade that to v7.

It's NOT possible to upgrade PowerShell 5.1 to PowerShell 7, the intended and only configuration, is a side-by-side configuration.  You are looking at the wrong path for PowerShell 7.  The message you receive has to do with PowerShell 6 or greater not PowerShell 5.1

The correct command(s) are winget search Microsoft.PowerShell and winget install --id Microsoft.Powershell --source winget the correct environment varaible is $env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\7 instead of C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

You will have to provide specification information on the reason the command "did not work".  You can also just install it through the MSI and skip the problem with winget

Thanks. I'll look to installing it separately. Side-by-side - I understand. So 5 stays in System32 and 7 gets installed in Program Files. I'll make sure 7 is before 5 in the PATH env variable. Cheers.
